# asl_add_log_file() to add a log output file to "NSLog"? (iOS)

Tags: ios

*I'm willing to put a bounty on this question. I already added one, but it expired without an answer to award it to. So if you know an answer, give me a hint and I will put another bounty on this.*

If I understand things correctly, asl is used behind `NSLog` calls. So I read the man pages and used google and eventually got the impression, that I could add an extra file to collect logging output with `asl_add_log_file` ([man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/asl_add_log_file.3.html)). As with other questions found using google, my output file is empty and no log messages appear there.

The usual solution so far seems to be to `freopen` the `stderr` to a file. I ran some tests and wanted to implement a trivial log rotation. When doing another `freopen` to a new file, some `NSLog` messages are lost. So I am looking for another solution.

To test it on Mac OS X, I created a console application in Xcode and added this code to main:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"docdir = %@", documentsDirectory);
    NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asl-created-%@.log",[NSDate date]];
    NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSLog(@"logFilePath = %@", logFilePath);

    int asl_fd = open([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], O_CREAT | O_APPEND);
    if (asl_fd==-1) {
        NSLog(@"could not open output file");
    }

    asl_object_t asl;
    asl = asl_open(NULL, NULL, 0);
    asl_add_log_file(asl, asl_fd);

    NSLog(@"test output");

    /* EDIT: added this */
    NSLog(@"YEAH! test output");
    asl_log(asl, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_ERR, "asl_log output");
    aslmsg asl_msg = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_MSG);
    asl_set(asl_msg, ASL_KEY_MSG, "asl test output");
    asl_set(asl_msg, ASL_KEY_HOST, "somehost");
    asl_send(asl, asl_msg);
    asl_free(asl_msg);
    /* (EDIT: added this) */


    asl_remove_log_file(asl, asl_fd);
    close(asl_fd);
```

EDIT: <del>However, as mentioned, the log file is empty. I would have expected, that "test output" appears in there.</del>
I added some asl log calls to test whether or not it works when using asl directly. The two messages logged via `asl_log` and `asl_send` do appear in the created file. However, the `NSLog` based log messages do not appear.

Is it possible to use `asl_add_log_file` to adjust the `NSLog` "backend"?

Comment: You can still use `asl` but instead of using `NSLog()` write your own interface.  ASL is slow though and you may as well stick with `fopen()` and `fprintf()` etc.  There is always CocoaLumberjack, but that is over engineered for such simple thing as logging.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your info - Yes, I know - however, the project in which I'd like to use the solution uses quite some Pods and I'd like to get their output as well. I assume that I wouldn't capture that when I'd roll my own interface / or use CocoaLumberjack.

Comment: Yeah you could use `dup2()` to dupe `stderr` onto your log file descriptor.

Comment: Hmmm - Thanks for the hint. I'll try `dup2()` within the next days and update my question with results.